# create constraint where only the trailing anchor can be shrink or expand

Tags: swift, slider, nslayoutconstraint, fixed

You can see in my gif below that the code below makes both the left and right side. What I want to do is only increase my right side. You can see in the gif where the red mark is of the side of I am only trying to increase it on the right side. I dont know how to just increase the right side and have the top left and bottom sides fixed.

[image]

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    var pic = UIView()
    var slizer = UISlider()
    var slidermultiplier: CGFloat = 0.3
    var widthConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        widthConstraints = pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)
        
        [pic,slizer].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pic.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            pic.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.3),
            widthConstraints!,
            
            slizer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            slizer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            slizer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.2),
            slizer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
        ])
        
        pic.backgroundColor = .orange
        // changed to .valueChanged
        slizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increase), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func increase() {
        slidermultiplier = CGFloat(slizer.value)
        widthConstraints?.isActive = false
        widthConstraints = pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)
        widthConstraints?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You have applied `pic.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)` which will keep your pic in center of the view (horizontally) and when slider slides you change the width, iOS is doing what you have asked it to do, its increasing width while keeping whole pic horizontally center, thats why left and right both sides are increasing while center reamains unmoved, remove center constraint, add leading constraint to pic and view and change width, only right side will move and left will be sticked to wherever it is

Comment: @SandeepBhandari can you code the answer I am confused i just need the constraint part. I will give you the credit. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment above, all you need is to remove `pic.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)` constraint and add `pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: whatver_value_you_think_is_correct)` for constant you can specify whatever value you see perfect your use case. If not sure what value to specify start with 0 :)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        widthConstraints = pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)

        [pic,slizer].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pic.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: whatver_value_you_think_is_correct),
            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.3),
            widthConstraints!,

            slizer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            slizer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            slizer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.2),
            slizer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
        ])

        pic.backgroundColor = .orange
        // changed to .valueChanged
        slizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increase), for: .valueChanged)
    }
```

Your existing `increase` method should work fine as is

Answer (score 0):

You can give your trailing constraint is greater than or equal to 0 (any constant according to your need) and make sure to fix the leading and other constraints.

Comment: can you code the answer I am confused i just need the constraint part. I will give you the credit. thanks